# threading.Timer gets cancelled but doesn't stop firing. Why?

Tags: scripting

I have an operator that starts a `threading.Timer` which moves the current frame forward by 3 every 5 seconds. If I call the same operator with the `stop` property set to True it must cancel the Timer.

I can see that the timer is now `NoneType` in the blender console

```
>>> type(C.scene.animall_timer.timer)
<class 'NoneType'>
```

but the Timer is still firing. Why is that?

Here is the relevant code:

```
def execute(op, context):
    print(op.stop)
    if context.scene.animall_timer.timer is not None: context.scene.animall_timer.timer.cancel()
    if not op.stop:
        context.scene.animall_timer.timer = threading.Timer(op.time, op.execute, [context]).start()
        context.scene.frame_set(context.scene.frame_current + op.frames)
        bpy.ops.anim.insert_keyframe_animall()
    return {'FINISHED'}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found it before I got to post the question, so instead of discarding it I will post the response myself.

The problem was that (coming from javascript and jquery) I was expecting Timer.start() to return the timer object, but it just returned `None` so cancelling it had no effect.

The working code is as:

```
def execute(op, context):
    print(op.stop)
    if context.scene.animall_timer.timer is not None: context.scene.animall_timer.timer.cancel()
    if not op.stop:
        context.scene.animall_timer.timer = threading.Timer(op.time, op.execute, [context])
        context.scene.animall_timer.timer.start()
        context.scene.frame_set(context.scene.frame_current + op.frames)
        bpy.ops.anim.insert_keyframe_animall()
    return {'FINISHED'}
```